# Logic for creating a tree like representation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, tree, logic

I have an requirement to show a binary tree like structure on the web page that will 
be used to represent parent-child relation. Unlike binary tree, this tree can have multiple child nodes
and the childs can have further children and this process will continue until no child left of their parent.

So, I am pretty much confused on how should my data-model should be and my thinking is not going beyond this one

```
public class Parent
{
  public string parentName {get;set;} // As their will be one start for this tree, I will have one parent node that will show the parent
  public List<string> child {get;set;} // As the parent can have multiple children, I can have a list of string 
}
```

But the question is that the child can also act as parent as they can also have children. How should I 
implement such structure.

Thanks

Comment: i would think this is simply a `tree-view` and not a binary tree.

Comment: Rather than having a left and right pointer for child nodes use an array

Answer (score 0):

A `string` can't have child elements of its own, so it's not a good representation.

A simple way is to make the child elements simply a `List` of the same type of element as the parent. Let's call them all `Node` instead:

```
public class Node
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public List<Node> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: using this answer do some research on `recursion` as well :-)